# Get a data id in modal using jquery and assign a variable

Tags: php, jquery

[image]

IF I click add button (like above image) with the id and name in href,how do I assign a variable after i get a data in modal like $_GET in php?

modal

```
     <tr>
  <td class="w3-padding-16" style="text-transform: capitalize"><?php echo $first_nameparty ?></td>
  <td class="w3-padding-16" style="text-transform: capitalize"><?php echo $last_nameparty ?></td>
  <td class="w3-padding-16" style="text-transform: capitalize"><?php echo $middle_nameparty ?></td>
  <td><a href="?party=<?php echo $resident_idparty ?>&partytwo=<?php echo $first_nameparty ?>&party3=<?php echo $last_nameparty ?>" class="w3-btn w3-green party">Add</a></td>

</tr>
```

js

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".party").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
     var puttingdata = $(this).attr("href");
       $("#puthere").text(puttingdata);


    });
});
```

This is will show and i dont know how to assign

[image]

```
<span id="puthere" class="w3-large" style="text-transform: capitalize;"><b></b></span>
```

Comment: If the modal loads a page via iframe, you can get the values passed using the $_GET variable.

Comment: i dont know if it is correct but it needs to reload before i can see the $_GET

Comment: i cant see it after  i click Add button but using var puttingdata = $(this).attr("href");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you need.
Use `data-*` attribute intead of `href`.

```
<td><button data-obj='{"party": <?php echo $resident_idparty ?>, "partytwo": "<?php echo $first_nameparty ?>", "party3": "<?php echo $last_nameparty ?>"}' class="w3-btn w3-green party">Add</button></td>
```

Then you can get the data object assigned in `puttingdata` variable.

```
var puttingdata = $(this).data("obj");
$("#puthere").text(puttingdata.party);
```

Comment: can i use as a variable like party for insert in database and 2 variables like partytwo and party3 as view name?

Answer (score 0):

It will reload when you are using href.

The $_GET syntax will only retrieve whats stated on the URL link, for eg.

```
// http://test.com?party=123
$var = $_GET['party']; // 123
```

If you do not want to reload the page, you should consider use AJAX

Comment: but the problem i cant get variable to assign it will also show the variable

Comment: maybe I have to look at the overview of your code, so i can see whats going on.

Comment: <button data-obj='{"party": <?php echo $resident_idparty ?>, "partytwo": "<?php echo $first_nameparty ?>", "party3": "<?php echo $last_nameparty ?>"}' class=" party">Add</button>

Comment: i have jquery like this $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".party").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    var puttingdata = $(this).data("obj");
    $("#puthere").text(puttingdata.party+ " " +puttingdata.partytwo + " " +puttingdata.party3 );
         $("#id0144").hide();
         $("#dissapear").hide();
     
    });
});

Comment: how can i use variable like party to assign for insert in database?

Comment: The php is a top down operation, if you want to use php $_GET to get the parameter item, you have to remove preventDefault and let it get the new URL to refresh, from there the php could $_GET parameter from URL